# How to get created login in SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql-server, authentication, triggers

I have a mirrored SQL Server database. I want to create a trigger on the principal database to capture any created, altered or dropped login and do same on the mirrored database, so I can use:

```
USE master
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trigger 
ON ALL SERVER AFTER CREATE_LOGIN, ALTER_LOGIN, DROP_LOGIN
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @name = name FROM Inserted

    PRINT('Trigger fired!' + @name)
END
```

but `Inserted` table in not supported in this trigger. I couldn't find any objects to get the created/updated login.

Do you have any idea how to get this details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDL triggers enable the use of the `eventdata()` function which returns an XML document describing the change that was just made. In your case, you can shred this XML to find out what login was created (and by whom if that's of interest to you).

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

/* For anybody needing an example of the tsql that would genreate the Trigger */

```
Use Master
GO

If Exists (Select * From sys.server_triggers where [name] = 'DDL_Trigger_Login_Changed')
    DROP TRIGGER [DDL_Trigger_Login_Changed] ON ALL SERVER
go

CREATE TRIGGER [DDL_Trigger_Login_Changed]
ON ALL SERVER
AFTER CREATE_LOGIN, ALTER_LOGIN, DROP_LOGIN
AS
Declare @results varchar(max)
Declare @subjectText varchar(max)
SET @subjectText = '*ALERT* DATABASE LOGIN changed on ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' by ' + SUSER_SNAME() 
SET @results = (SELECT EVENTDATA().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)'))

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = '<Change This value to be the email profile you want to use>',
    @recipients = '<Change This value to be the email address you want to use>',
    @body = @results,
    @subject = @subjectText,
    @exclude_query_output = 1 --Suppress 'Mail Queued' message
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.